# GNOME 3.2 Menu Not Loading

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

Gnome 3.2 Menu is not loading.  I wanted to add a minimize and maximize to the right of my windows.  So I did the following:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout  --type string "menu:minimize,maximize,close"
```

logout and login that it per the instructions of this website: [Instructions](http://mihirknows.blogspot.com/2011/10/solution-ubuntu-1110-minimize-maximize.html)

I logged out and back in and that was it.  No menu.  Help!!!

- By the way, there is a fix on this website to restore Gnome. However it did not work.
- Another odd thing was that Gnome Tweak Tool is black under the Shell Extension tab.

Comment: When you say "Gnome 3.2 Menu" what are we talking about? I only ask because the snippet you include doesn't really do anything with menus, rather the window buttons (minimise,maximise,close). Want to make sure you're using the right terminology or people won't understand what you're talking about :)

Answer (score 1):

`gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/metacity/general/button_layout menu:minimize,maximize,close` , and try rebooting system
or

Interesting as

```
gconf-editor >Apps > Metacity > General > button_layout shows
close,maximize,minimize:menu
```

Comment: No go,the menu won't load. It kinda flashes for a quick second and is gone.